# Is it possible to automate a chart browsing with screen capture on Trading view?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I would like to get a script that will capture the screen of my Trading view's chart for all of the symbols that I need to monitor (around 300 symbols).

What I need to see on my chart is just 2 EMA and volume. And I need the script to upload the screen to FTP or somewhere else and I can review all of it easily.

Well, I cannot browse my chart link without logging in. So, this may not be possible.
But if there is some way to do it, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible through pinescript. You can use Python together with Selenium (browser automation) though.

Comment: Thank you, I found that Python can do this for me.